# How to make a docusign API app certified?

Tags: docusignapi

Today my DocuSign App is ready but I don't have any idea how to make it work to public. To remove the DEMO watermark on the documents. In short how to make it certified. Do we need to fill up something like a form or do we need to submit our app or maybe we need a non-developer account for this?

Please advice, any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't be asking this question in the first place. I hope you realized that. Thank you for the comment :)

Comment: I understand that but on Stack Overflow you have to put in a good amount of effort to find the answer before posting on SO. We don't just do your work for you. You have to show that you put a good amount of effort into finding the solution before posting.

Comment: well I did, so I did asked and that make sense right? Unless I'm asking on the wrong place. Well thank you anyway buddy. You're a great help :)

Comment: So if you did what kind of effort did you put in? What have you researched so far?

Comment: a lot of effort. happy now?

Comment: I'm just saying that is probably why you have 2 down votes. Giving detail about what you have tried so far and what research you have done goes a LONG way on SO.

Comment: 2 down votes including yours. So the other is counted not yours. Anyway, it's settled now. You're such a great help really, appreciate it I REALLY do., keep it up buddy:) more reps to go. Almost there, road to gold :)

Comment: And what proof do you have that I down voted?? Accusing people without proof isn't cool.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the DocuSign Developer Center and click the section that says "Ready to Go Live?" you'll find what you're looking for.

That leads to the Go Live section which tells you how to go live:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live

Further down in that section you'll see a bright blue button that says "**START API CERTIFICATION PROCESS**" which kicks off a powerform that you use to certify your app.